# Angular JS loading initial view into homepage..slow load

Tags: angularjs, view, angular-ui-router

So in my Angular JS page I have my Index page which has i.e the head and footer of my page..and the main container gets loaded by a view like this

```
<!-- container -->
<div ui-view></div>
<!-- /container -->

app.config(['$stateProvider','$urlRouterProvider','$locationProvider', 

    function($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider){
      'use strict';

      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");

      $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
          url: '/',
          templateUrl: '/views/search.html',
          controller: 'SearchCtrl'
        })
        .state('result', {
          url: '/result',
          templateUrl: '/views/result.html',
          controller: 'resultCtrl'
        });


      $locationProvider.html5Mode(false);
    }]);
```

The problem is on the initial load on the homepage it is very noticeable the main content gets loaded after the header and footer..its like initial page is very slow and then expands when the view gets loaded.

Is there anyway to improve this performance ?

Comment: Do you want to improve performance or do you want to hide the header/footer until everything is ready?

Comment: I suppose I am looking for everything to load at the same time yeah, I dont want the jumpyness in the page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least one reason for slowness is that the template for the view (`'/views/search.html'`) is obtained asynchronously. One way to improve is to add the template inline (for example, in index.html) with a `<script>` tag:

```
<script type="text/ng-template" id="/views/search.html">
 ... template
</script>
```

Comment: How does this work with UI-Router and changing states ?

Comment: It works the same way as you specified above, except "/views/search.html" will be retrieved not from a URL but rather from a template cache